# split data numbers into two columns in shell script

Tags: shell

I have numbers from 1 to 1000 in file ($y).

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
echo "$i" >> $y
done
```

I want to split numbers into two column in the file(user enters the filename that indicates "$y").

```
1    501
.    .
.    .
500  1000
```

like this.

I tried `split -l500 $y` and `column -t` command but couldn't get expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do:

```
printf '%d\t%d\n' {1..100} 
1    2
3    4
5    6
[...]
```

Then:

```
printf '%d\t%d\n' {1..100} | while read i; do
        echo "$i" >> "$y"
    done
```